# Retrieve different data from one column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose a table have a column with values like:

```
    column
    3
    1
    1
    3
    4
    1
    2
```

I want to retrieve that how many times there is 1 in column and how many times > 1.
Is there anyway to do this within one query?

I want the data to be fetched like this:

```
one | greater_than_one
 3  |        4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
select sum(col1=1) as one , 
       sum(col1>1) as greater_than_one
from test_tbl;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/348f5YOK

Comment: Thanks buddy! your code works but I don't get it that how sum is working? Because it sums up the values not count it.

Comment: It sums the *result of the expression*